# Remove item from list after filtering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following issue:

I've create a list that allow the user to delete an item from list, as following:

[image]

When user click on trash icon, the item is removed normally.
The problem is when the user uses the filter on top.

[image]

In that case, if I delete the number 6565 (index 4 in original list, 1 on filtered list), the item deleted is on index 1 on original list, resulting on delete the register with number #564456

This is my delete call on click:

```
 $scope.deleteOwn = function (uuid) {
    console.log(uuid);
    var coupon = $scope.ownsCoupons[uuid];
    Coupon.delete({'id' : coupon.uuid}, function () {
        $scope.ownsCoupons.splice(uuid, 1);
    });
}
```

And this is my html template:

```
<td><a href="" ><i class="icon-trash" ng-click="deleteOwn($index)"></i></a></td>
```

I also try to use the code: `$scope.ownsCoupons.splice(coupon, 1);`without success.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

I've coded using the following reference: [AngularJS How to remove an Item from scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250642/angularjs-how-to-remove-and-item-from-scope)

**[EDIT]**

I've created a Plunker to this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fhxp6uZyTJCY05CAQ7yA?p=preview

Comment: You can't relay on indexes, use object references instead. Not sure why splice didn't work for you. You need to share more code (ideally live with plunker) so people can help you more.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I've updated the question with the plunker.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned by @pkozlowski.opensource, you can't depend on `$index` to identify an item in an array in this way. I would make the following changes:

HTML:

```html
<td><a ng-click="deleteWish(coupon)"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
```

JS:

```javascript
$scope.deleteWish = function (coupon) {
    var index = $scope.coupons.indexOf(coupon);
    if (index != -1) {
        $scope.coupons.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0b2cYGsM5wtw8hIrQB5?p=preview

Comment: Hey Brandon, could you explain what the (index != -1) is exactly doing? Thanks.

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness `array.indexOf(item)` returns `-1` if `item` is not found in `array`. If `index != -1`, then the item was found, and can be removed.