# Angular - splice removes anything but the needed object from the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to remove contacts from my simple Phonebook app. However when I invoke the deletePerson function, I remove anything but the needed contact. Please show me my mistake guys.

My contacts partial:

```
<ul class="people-list">
    <li showhideoptions ng-repeat="person in people | filter: search | 
                                   orderBy: 'name' | orderBy:'friend':true">
        <h4>
            <span ng-show="person.friend==true" class="icon-star icon-left"></span>
            <span ng-show="person.friend==false" class="icon-user icon-left"></span>

        {{person.name}}

        <span ng-click="deletePerson($index)"
          class="icon-remove pull-right"></span>
          </h4>

    </li>
</ul>
```

My main controller with factory:

```
var app = angular.module('contactList');

app.factory('simpleFactory', function(){
    var people = [
            {name: 'Collin', city: 'Omaha', friend: false},
            {name: 'Alice', city: 'New York', friend: false},
            {name: 'Pasha', city: 'Moscow', friend: true},
            {name: 'Denis', city: 'St. Pete', friend: true}

    ];

    var factory = {};
    factory.getPeople = function() {
        return people;
    };

    return factory;
});

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, simpleFactory) {

$scope.people = [];

init();

function init() {
    $scope.people = simpleFactory.getPeople();
}

$scope.addPerson = function() {
    $scope.people.push(
    {   name: $scope.newPerson.name, 
        city: $scope.newPerson.city,
        friend: false
    });
};

$scope.deletePerson = function($index) {
    $scope.people.splice($index, 1);
}
  });
```

**UPD**

I now understand that the filter

```
 | filter: search | orderBy: 'name' | orderBy:'friend':true"
```

Makes my deleting process go crazy. If anyone could advise me on how to tackle this problem, I'd appreciate that!

Comment: What's wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/DARbK/ ?

Comment: @Cherniv mine deletes Contacts randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete using the item itself, something like

**HTML**

```
 <span ng-click="deletePerson(person)"
          class="icon-remove pull-right">
 </span>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.deletePerson = function(item) {
    $scope.people.splice($scope.people.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266712/remove-item-from-list-after-filtering