# Removing an object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-rootscope

I have a $rootScope object in AngularJS like this:

```
$rootScope.stuff = {
    someId: {
        name: "Patrick",
        age: 105
    },
    anotherId: {
        name: "Joseph",
        age: 94
    }
};
```

I have a function defined that adds objects to $rootScope.stuff, and it works fine:

```
$rootScope.addSomeStuff = function(id, data) {
    $rootScope.stuff[id] = data;
};
```

However, I also have a function that tries to delete (based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), and it is not working:

```
$rootScope.deleteStuff = function(id) {
    delete $rootScope.stuff[id];
};
```

When I check `$rootScope.stuff[id]` I am getting the correct object that I want to delete. I have also tried splice, but that throws an error like I thought it would. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show me what you did for your splice function?

Comment: Sure. `$rootScope.stuff.splice($rootScope.stuff[id], 1);` And I got the error "TypeError: $rootScope.stuff.splice is not a function."

Comment: Why don't you think it works? Is there an error?

Comment: Just to confirm - you named the arg that you're passing into the delete method "id" but you're actually passing in the index of the object you want to delect, correct?  $rootScope.deleteStuff = function(index)

Comment: Splice only works on arrays, correct? $rootScope.stuff is just an object.

Comment: @psnoonan -- Why dont you think `delete $rootScope.stuff[id];` works?

Comment: Thanks, I should of asked to see your markup. It might be worth looking at this answer if you have similar markup.
[How to remove elements/nodes from angular.js array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18303310/4498202)

Comment: @tymeJV -- I am getting "TypeError: $rootScope.stuff.splice is not a function."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the object to an array of objects, then pass in the index of the object you want to delete:

```
$rootScope.stuff = [
    someId: {
        name: "Patrick",
        age: 105
    },
    anotherId: {
        name: "Joseph",
        age: 94
    }
];



$rootScope.deleteStuff = function(index) {
    delete $rootScope.stuff[index];
};
```

HTML (assuming this is rendered via ng-repeat):

```
<button ng-click="deleteStuff($index)"></button>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to keep the data as an object, it will be a difficult data structure to work with because the ID of each object is actually not an ID but an object with a name and an age. So, I actually don't know if it'll be possible to delete the entire object. You could delete the name and the age but without a unique identifier for the whole object I don't know how you'd delete the object itself.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure that will work, but I still want to know why delete doesn't work if I want to keep it as an object and not an array.

Comment: It is in this answer, but not in how my code is set up. It is one big object. when I check `angular.isArray($rootScope.stuff);` I get false. And I also get `TypeError: $rootScope.stuff.splice is not a function` when I try to use splice.

Comment: for objects you use dot notation to identify the value of the key that you want to delete like this "delete stuff.someId.name" - but since you don't have an actual ID for the object you're deleting it may be impossible to delete it.