# Removing items from array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this two integers arrays:
I am working on my Angularjs tutorial project.

In controller I have this two arrays:

```
var arrA=[12,54,76,98,45];
var arrB=[12,98];
```

I need to delete from **arrA** all numbers that inside **arrB**.

**arrA** have to be like this after implementation:

```
arrA=[54,76,45]
```

What is best and elegantic way to implement it in angularjs?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303040/how-to-remove-elements-nodes-from-angular-js-array,

Comment: You can find your answer in 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```js
var arrA=[12,54,76,98,45];
var arrB=[12,98];

arrA = arrA.filter(function(o){
  return arrB.indexOf(o) == -1;
  });

document.write(JSON.stringify(arrA));
```

Comment: @Michael, that's simple plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head.

```
//Run a loop to go through all elements in arrB
for (var i=0;i<arrB.length;i++) {
   //keep position of element i in arrA
   //if it's not there index will be equal to -1
   var index=arrA.indexOf(arrB[i])
   //if it is there
   if(index!=-1) {
   //remove 1 element at position index from arrA
    arrA.splice(index,1)
   }
}
```

Good luck. 
This has nothing to do with angular btw, it's basic javascript.

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/MichaelSel/t2dfg31c/

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't concern itself with things like array manipulation. JavaScript provides facilities for that though:

```
var diff = arrA.filter(function(item) {
    return arrB.indexOf(item) < 0;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyznhcyb/)

If arrB is very large, you might want to allow it to be O(N) (for smallish ones) up to O(N log N), instead of O(n^2):

```
var lookup = arrB.reduce(function(lookup, item) {
    lookup[item] = true;
    return lookup;
}, {});
diff = arrA.filter(function(item) {
    return !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(lookup, item);
});
```

However, this only works if the string representation of the item is what you are looking at. It would work for integers.

Answer (score 1):

how about the following:

```
var result = arrA.filter(function(elem){
  return arrB.indexOf(elem) === -1;
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete items from any array you need to use splice:

```js
$scope.items.splice(index, 1);
```

now what you can do is, you can run a for loop to identify the duplicate element. Once identified you can remove it using splice function.