# How to remove element from array using angularjs?

Tags: javascript

Once i rendered data from backend i want to remove element `id` from the array how can i achieve that using angularjs ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.array =  [{
        "name": "Java Class",
        "id": "javaClass",
        "createdBy": "shu",
        "__v": 0,
        "properties": [{
            "label": "Java Package Name",
            "type": "String",
            "editable": true,
            "binding": {
                "type": "property",
                "name": "camunda:class"
            }
        }],
        "appliesTo": ["bpmn:ServiceTask"]
    }]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove elements/nodes from angular.js array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303040/how-to-remove-elements-nodes-from-angular-js-array)

Comment: The element at index `0` of `$scope.array` is an object, not an array.

Comment: @phemt.latd OP is attempting to remove a property from an object, not an element from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `delete`

```
delete $scope.array[0].id;
```