# How to pass anything from DOM-element into function defined in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objList">
    <input type="text" id="obj_{{obj.id}}"/>
    <button ng-click="removeRow(NEED PARAM HERE)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

I could use button's id or maybe parent's, but I dont know exactly how.

And second similar case: when I want get some value from input, for example. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass  `obj`  in your function, and then remove the object `obj` from `objList` in your controller, it will disappear from your view, that's how angular's data binding works :

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objList">
  <input type="text" id="obj_{{obj.id}}"/>
  <button ng-click="removeRow(obj)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

And in you controller:

```
$scope.removeRow = function(obj) { 
  var index = $scope.objList.indexOf(obj);
  $scope.objList.splice(index, 1);     
}
```

Comment: Works well, thanks! But if I want pass value from textfield, what can I do here? Oh, and please one more question: how can I bind value from input field to some field in obj?

Comment: You can try : `<input type="text" ng-model="obj.text" id="obj_{{obj.id}}"/>` and then pass `obj` or `obj.text` to a function in your controller, the same way as above.

Comment: it's looks a little stange - to create a new model for each element... or no? :)

Comment: Each element is already bound to the model with your ng-repeat, you just add a property to those objetcs.

Answer (score 3):

A little hard to follow your question, but are you trying to pass the `value` from the text field to the function so you can remove the row from the list?

If that is true then the you want to do something like this.

You'll want to use the ngRepeat `track by` functionality. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objList track by $index">
  <input type="text" id="obj_{{obj.id}}" />
  <button ng-click="removeRow($index)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

At that point you're just using basic Javascript `splice` functionality to remove an item from an `Array` by index. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**JS**

```
 $scope.removeRow = function($index) {
  $scope.objList.splice($index, 1);
};
```

See also [AngularJS How to remove an Item from scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250642/angularjs-how-to-remove-an-item-from-scope?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Beware of `$index` if `objList` is filtered in the template ! It is safer to directly use the object.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @deonclem, we normally do our filtering via an API and then update the $scope, so we haven't run into this yet. Appreciate the tip!