# Ionic list: swipe to remove?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ionic-framework

Is there any possibility to implement "swipe-to-remove" (like in Android task-screen) functionality with "ion-list"?

I have found "can-swipe" directive that allows to add some buttons which appear under partly-swiped item, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need to fully swipe an item (both sides) and remove it when it becomes swiped to the end of the screen.

Comment: What happens if you use on-swipe on the top level list? Obviously by itself it won't do anything, but add a console.log msg to the handler and see if it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems like "ion-list" doesn't have built in "swipe-to-delete" functionality.

Nevertheless I implemented it using [Hammer Plugin for Angular.js](http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/) and some custom directives and logic. That allowed to make list-items be swipeable. And then I used [How to remove an item from scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250642/angularjs-how-to-remove-an-item-from-scope) technology for actual elements removal.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend doing what Dmytro suggested, there is an easy way to do this.

Use the [expandable options](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/#usage):

Add `#ionItem` to the `ion-item` being swiped, and add `side="end"` and the `(ionSwipe)` event to the `ion-item-options` in your HTML.

```
<ion-item #ionItem>
</ion-item>
<ion-item-options side="end" (ionSwipe)="swipedNotification(ionItem)">
    <ion-item-option class="notifications-swipe-button" expandable>&nbsp;</ion-item-option>
</ion-item-options>
```

And in your css, make the width of the button 30px so you can trigger ionSwipe, which isn't called if the width is too large:

```
.notifications-swipe-button{
    width: 30px; 
}
```

And in your ts file, on add your function that to be called on `(ionSwipe)` in your HTML, and animate the content all the way to the left:

```
swipedNotification(el){
    el.el.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(-100vw), 0px, 0px)`;
}
```

Keep in mind, this is set up to swipe left to dismiss, if you want to swipe right, you will have to update the x property in translate3d.