# AngularJS: Delete clicked elements parent row

Tags: angularjs

I have a table of users, each row representing a user.
On the end of each row I have a delete link, which when clicked deletes the user from database.

Now I need to update the table to reflect the changes.
I know how I would do this with jQuery, but how do I do it the angular way?
Do I need to add a `ng-model` attribute to each row?

This is how I have attached the click event:

```
<a ng-click="deleteUser(user._id)">Delete</a>
```

I have a `<tr ng-repeat="user in users"></tr>` printing out the users. I'm thinking if I remove the user from the model, that might be the way to go.

EDIT: I found now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250642/angularjs-how-to-remove-an-item-from-scope) question, which also answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Use `ng-repeat` to render the list of users and on delete remove the user from the users list. Since it's a two way binding it will dynamically update the tr's.

Also on ng-click, you would need to call a `$http` service which will tell the database to delete the required user from DB. Use factory/service to create a $http service.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the `$http` service from Angular.