# Can not remove object from $scope in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I am doing following on a call back.

```
$scope.summary = data;
```

Once summary object is part of $scope i cant delete it programatically on another event like following.

```
delete $scope.summary
```

Above line returns true but the object is still there with all data.
Btw if I do the following it deletes the object successfully.

```
delete $scope.summary.abc
```

It would be great if you can shed light on this and guide me through this.

Comment: Add more code or a jsfiddle to help you out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS How to remove an Item from scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250642/angularjs-how-to-remove-an-item-from-scope)

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/Lvc0u55v/42/

Comment: The snippet you show should work but, why do you want to delete a variable instead of assigning `null` or `undefined` to it? I'm curious

Answer (score 0):

Are you deleting the property "Summary" in the right $scope?

There is possibility you want to delete "summary" property of the $parent $scope.  Without some code it is hard to tell.